# Does pika confirm_delivery mean confirm when broker got the message or when consumer acknowledged?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, pika

From my producer code I want to know when the consumer has `basic.ack`ed a message.

Using `channel.confirm_delivery()` and a `BlockingConnection` it is not clear from the documentation if this should confirm 1) the broker having received the message, or, 2) a consumer having acknowledge receiving it.

Running this code (with no consumer):

```
import pika
import uuid

# Open a connection to RabbitMQ on localhost using all default parameters
connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
# Open the channel
channel = connection.channel()
queue = str(uuid.uuid4())

# Declare the queue
channel.queue_declare(queue=queue)

# Turn on delivery confirmations
channel.confirm_delivery()

# Send a message
if channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                         routing_key=queue,
                         body='Hello World!',
                         properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                             content_type='text/plain',
                             delivery_mode=1)):
    print('Message publish was confirmed')
else:
    print('Message could not be confirmed')
```

shows the message to be confirmed.  This is not what I expect or want.

This may be a duplicate of
[Behavior of channels in "confirm" mode with RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340696/behavior-of-channels-in-confirm-mode-with-rabbitmq) however the documentation for [basic_publish](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/_modules/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.html?highlight=basic_publish) says

> :returns: True if delivery confirmation is not enabled (NEW in pika
>               0.10.0); otherwise returns False if the message could not be
>               deliveved (Basic.nack and/or Basic.Return) and True if the message
>               was delivered (Basic.ack and no Basic.Return)

which makes me think it should have the I wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`confirm_deliveries` just means that when **RabbitMQ** has received a message, either a basic.ack (message received) or basic.nack (message not received) will be returned.

This does however not guarantee that the message was successfully delivered to a queue. You will need to add the mandatory flag for an unroutable message to throw an exception.

You can read more about confirm deliveries and the mandatory flag [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html).

Answering your question; there is no way for the publisher to know if a consumer successfully handled the message. However, if a consumer fails to consume a message, it should be re-queued and handle by another consumer, but that depends on how well the consumers were designed.

If you really need to know if a message has been handled properly, implementing something like an RPC call that replies back with the status of the request may be the best approach. If you don't get a response within X seconds, assume that the message wasn't handled. 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

If you need a async example for rpc publishers you can take a look at some of my examples for flask [here](https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/tree/master/Flask-examples).

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing this up - indeed this is what I found out after some testing.